# Compare values of 2 uneven vectors and choose the bigger value

Tags: r

I have 2 vectors of value that I extracted from a .pdf file which represents the location of two different keywords. vector.1 is the first keyword while vector.2 is the second keyword. So I need to extract all the rows in between using something like below.

df.1 <- df[vector.1[1]:vector.2[1], ]

I managed to use a loop to go through all the vectors for other documents but for this particular file, it has uneven location due to the structure of it.

```
vector.1 <- c(12, 85, 144, 188, 233, 285, 338, 384, 426, 469, 512, 558, 613, 669, 713, 758, 808, 859, 908, 964, 1046, 1090, 1126, 1149, 1216, 1267, 1346, 1423, 1464, 1513, 1560, 1607, 1665, 1718, 1763, 1810, 1856, 1908, 1938)

vector.2 <- c(48, 53, 111, 116, 155, 160, 198, 203, 250, 255, 303, 308, 350, 355, 392, 397, 435, 440, 478, 483, 523, 528, 578, 583, 635, 640, 679, 684, 723, 728, 773, 778, 824, 829, 871, 876, 929, 934, 1008, 1017, 1091, 1096, 1182, 1187, 1232, 1237, 1308, 1313, 1385, 1390, 1430, 1435, 1478, 1483, 1525, 1530, 1572, 1577, 1629, 1634, 1683, 1688, 1729, 1734, 1776, 1781, 1821, 1826, 1874, 1879, 1967, 1972)
```

As you can see vector.1[2] is bigger than vector.2[2] and the actual location is supposed to be vector.2[3]. Is there anyway to write the code to match each vector[i] so that the desired result is something like below:

```
vector.3 <- c(48, 111, 155, 198, 250, 303, 392, 435, ....)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am very confused how you get your result. *"As you can see vector.1[2] is bigger than vector.2[2] and the actual location is supposed to be vector.2[3]"* -- I can see that `vector.1[2]` is bigger than `vector.2[2]`, but how am I supposed to know that the actual location is `vector.2[3]`? Can you walk us through the first few values? It seems like you want every other value from `vector.2` until 392, which skips very far ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector.2[rowSums(outer(vector.1,vector.2,">"))+1]
 [1]   48  111  155  198  250  303  350  392  435  478  523  578  635  679  723  773  824  871  929
[20] 1008 1091 1091 1182 1182 1232 1308 1385 1430 1478 1525 1572 1629 1683 1729 1776 1821 1874 1967
[39] 1967
```

You can also do `vector.2[colSums(sapply(vector.1,">",vector.2))+1]`

Comment: If this work, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check beside the answer and/or upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract particular values from vector.2 into another vector.3  this should do, provided the indexes follow a sequence separated by 2.  You can generate a sequence of indices using seq by providing the start and end index and the increment by arguments accordingly.

```
vector.3 <-  vector.2[seq(1,length(vector.2),by=2)]
 [1]   48  111  155  198  250  303  350  392  435  478
[11]  523  578  635  679  723  773  824  871  929 1008
[21] 1091 1182 1232 1308 1385 1430 1478 1525 1572 1629
[31] 1683 1729 1776 1821 1874 1967
```

Comment: Thank for the help but there are no specific sequence or trend.

Answer (score 0):

Or do you want the smallest value of `vector.2` that is larger than each value of `vector.1`?...

```
sapply(vector.1, function(x) min(vector.2[vector.2>x]))

 [1]   48  111  155  198  250  303  350  392  435  478  523  578  635  679  723  773  824  871  929 1008 1091 1091 1182
[24] 1182 1232 1308 1385 1430 1478 1525 1572 1629 1683 1729 1776 1821 1874 1967 1967
```